# Webpack DefinePlugin in Karma (how to access vaiables?)

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-runner

I have an Angular 2 project building with Webpack.

I use DefinePlugin to pass variables (such as ENV) to the application.

For unit testing I do the same (ie. use DefinePlugin in webpack.test.js too)

In my tests, I want to be able to change the variables to be able to access some branches. For example:

```
showMonitor = (ENV === 'development' && !AOT);
```

In my test spec, I want to simulate AOT being false

How can I access AOT from the test spec? I have a fixture and component instance as follows:

```
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
const instance = fixture.componentInstance;
```

But I can't access AOT since its a global variable defined by the DefinePlugin

Any ideas will help a lot!

Cheers!